# Sentences of positive, negative and interrogative

Tags: sentence-construction

Which ones are correct between, example of sentence future tense in positive sentence "I will close the door" and then for negative sentence "I will not open the door" and interrogative sentence" will you open the door?" Or in positive sentence "I will close the door" and the in negative sentence "I will not close the door" and also in interrogative sentence "will I close the door?"

Comment: There are lots of good and free spelling checkers on the internet.  Please use one of these to help your spelling. It will make people more likely to read and pay attention to your writing.

Comment: All the examples are OK. They just fit in different parts of a conversation.